# How to find and click an image link using the image's src (Selenium, Python)

Tags: python, selenium

I would like to click an image link and I need to be able to find it by its src, however it's still not working for some reason. Is this even possible? This is what I'm trying:

```
#Find item
item = WebDriverWait(driver, 100000).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//img[@src=link]")))
#item = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//img[@alt='Bzs36xl9 xa']")))
item.click()
```

link = //assets.supremenewyork.com/170065/vi/BZS36xl9-xA.jpg in the above code. This matches the HTML from below.
The second locator works (finding image using alt), but I will only have the image source when the program actually runs.

HTML for the webpage:

```
<article>
   <div class="inner-article">
      <a style="height:81px;" href="/shop/accessories/h68lyxo2h/llhxzvydj">
         <img width="81" height="81" src="//assets.supremenewyork.com/170065/vi/BZS36xl9-xA.jpg" alt="Bzs36xl9 xa">
      </a>
   </div>
</article>
```

I don't see why finding by alt would work and not src, is this possible? I saw another similar question which is where I got my solution but it didn't work for me. Thanks in advance.

EDIT
To find the link I have to parse through a website in JSON format, here's the code:

```
#Loads Supreme JSON website into an object
url = urllib2.urlopen('https://www.supremenewyork.com/mobile_stock.json')
obj = json.load(url)

items = obj["products_and_categories"]["Accessories"]

itm_name = "Sock"
index = 0;
for i in items:
        if(itm_name in items[index]["name"]):
                found_url = i["image_url"]
                break
        index += 1

str_link = str(found_url)
link = str_link.replace("ca","vi")
```

Comment: can you show in your code where you defined link?

Comment: and this parsed link string is always == the actual element src?

Comment: From the few items that I've tried locating, the parsed link string (after I replace the ca) is == to the src on the website. And the link that I posted matches the src exactly in the html, which is why I'm confused that it isn't working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `WebDriverWait` and `element_to_be_clickable`.Try the following xpath.Hope this will work.

```
link ='//assets.supremenewyork.com/170065/vi/BZS36xl9-xA.jpg'
item = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='inner-article']/a/img[@src='{}']".format(link))))
print(item.get_attribute('src'))
item.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> item = WebDriverWait(driver, 100000).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//img[@src=link]")))
> ```

Heres your problem, I can't believe it didn't jump out at me. You're asking the driver to find an element with a src of "link" NOT the variable link that you've defined earlier. Idk how to pass in variables into xpaths but i do know that you can use stringFormat to create the correct xpath string just before calling it.

i also dont speak python, so here's some pseudo java/c# to help you get the picture

```
String xPathString = String.Format("//img[@src='{0}']", link);
item = WebDriverWait(driver, 100000).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xPathString)))
```

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work:

   item = WebDriverWait(driver, 100000).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//img[@src={}]".format(link))))

Comment: please format the string before passing it into the xpath and copy your code and the xpath string with any further problems